# Authorize.NET Direct Post Method WebForms (C#) sample implementation

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am seeking a sample implementation of Authorize.Net DPM using Webforms, but I can't find it even in Authorize.net website, they have only an MVC example. Anyone who has a sample implementation using WebForm (C#)?

Comment: I believe the mvc sample would still show what needs to be sent, regardless of MVC or Webform, just adapt it to what you want.

Comment: if anyone has an alternative solution rather than the below answers, please post it here to help others needing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To those who need a solution, I found this link : http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Direct-Post-Method-DPM-code-sample-for-C-ASP-NET-web-forms-non/td-p/8574

Answer (score 0):

i have done it and it works fine with web forms.i would say look at the java code(not the usual way but it worked for me,it gives you a simple form needed just to create a simple request),create a simple form on its lines,post it through and then receive the response.
Hope it helps.I am assuming you already have a test account and an api key.

Comment: i must add i did about a year back,so there might be a few minor changes to the sdk.

Comment: @ashutosh-I appreciate it if you post your code, it helps also to others who needs it. :)